# Pandas pct_change with data containing NaN results in nonsensical values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, nan

I'm very confused by the output of the pct_change function when data with NaN values are involved. The first several rows of output in the right column are correct - it gives the percentage change in decimal form of the cell to the left in Column A relative to the cell in Column A two rows prior. But as soon as it reaches the NaN values in Column A, the output of the pct_change function makes no sense.

For example:

```
Row 8: NaN is 50% greater than 2?

Row 9: NaN is 0% greater than 3? 

Row 11: 4 is 33% greater than NaN?

Row 12: 2 is 33% less than NaN?`
```

Based on the above math, it seems like pct_change is assigning NaN a value of "3". Is that because pct_change effectively fills forward the last non-NaN value? Could someone please explain the logic here and why this happens?

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({'A': [2,1,3,1,4,5,2,3,np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,4,2,1,0,4]})
x = 2
df['pctchg_A'] = df['A'].pct_change(periods = x)

print(df.to_string())
```

Here's the output:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**The behaviour is as expected**. You need to carefully read the [`df.pct_change docs`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pct_change.html).

As per docs:

```
fill_method: str, default ‘pad’
How to handle NAs before computing percent changes.
```

Here, **method `pad`** means, it will `forward-fill` the `NaN` values with the nearest `non-NaN` value.

So, if you `ffill or pad` your `NaN` values, you will understand what's exactly happening. Check this out:

```
In [3201]: df['padded_A'] = df['A'].fillna(method='pad')

In [3203]: df['pctchg_A'] = df['A'].pct_change(periods = x)

In [3204]: df
Out[3204]: 
      A  padded_A  pctchg_A
0   2.0       2.0       NaN
1   1.0       1.0       NaN
2   3.0       3.0  0.500000
3   1.0       1.0  0.000000
4   4.0       4.0  0.333333
5   5.0       5.0  4.000000
6   2.0       2.0 -0.500000
7   3.0       3.0 -0.400000
8   NaN       3.0  0.500000
9   NaN       3.0  0.000000
10  NaN       3.0  0.000000
11  4.0       4.0  0.333333
12  2.0       2.0 -0.333333
13  1.0       1.0 -0.750000
14  0.0       0.0 -1.000000
15  4.0       4.0  3.000000
```

Now you can compare `padded_A` values with `pctchg_A` and see that it works as expected.

Comment: Thank you - this makes sense. I'm still learning and while I'm familiar with fillna, I didn't understand the meaning of "pad". In looking at the docs, I see that "pad" is the default method - how can I see the other options for fill_method? For example, I would prefer to have the result just be "NaN" whenever there's a "NaN" involved in the calc from Column A.

Comment: Check [`this`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.fillna.html) out for `fillna`.